# Can an iMac be used as an external monitor with the 2018 iPad Pro as the source?

Tags: macos, ipad, mac, display, imac

Apple just released the new iPad and as one can clearly see Apple showed how we can use it with an external monitor via the USB-C Port. So, my question is can the same principle/procedure be used for an iMac?

For now it supports only some Digital Cameras and External Displays. Several experimental videos show that it is unable to detect any external drive. I also looked for manuals and detailed product information on Apple's website - Alas! couldn't find anything valuable.

Comment: Can this be answered if nobody has the iPad Pro they just announced today?  Is that your question or is it something else?  It's hard to tell by the way the question is worded.